# How do you tell if an equation makes a circle?

Tags: linear-algebra, circles

For instance the equation, $$(x-3)^2+(y+4)^2=25$$ would be graphed as a circle. Is there a way to see that an equation creates a circle without graphing it? Is there a certain set of criteria it must fit or a generic base equation, or is it just random? Thank you.

Comment: It definitely ain't random.  If you know the distance formula, this just says the distance from a point to the center is a constant, which is exactly what makes a circle a circle.

Comment: I mean, $(x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = r^2$ is the "base equation" for a circle, centered at $(h,k)$, with radius $r$. I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Take a general equation of a curve  $ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$
If $abc+2fgh-af^2-bg^2-ch^2 \not=0$  ;  $ab-h^2>0$  ; $a=b$ and $h=0$;
We can say that $ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$ is a circle.

Or else as stated in comments,from the distance formula we deduce that,the general form of a circle of radius $r$ centered at $(h,k)$ is
$(x−h)^2+(y−k)^2=r^2$